# Node.js streaming backpressure handling between services

Tags: node.js, streaming

I am quite new to node.js and don't fully understand the concept of streams. Why does the provider service's write buffer depend on the consumer service's operating speed? Shouldn't the provider have no idea what the state of the consumer's read buffer is in an HTTP based communication?

The provider service's code:

```
import express from 'express';
import mockData from './mockData.js';
import { Readable } from 'stream';

const app = express();

function createDataSource() {
  return Readable.from(mockData);
}

app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

  const readableStream = createDataSource();

  readableStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    const shouldContinue = res.write(chunk);
    if (!shouldContinue) {
      readableStream.pause();

      res.once('drain', () => {
        readableStream.resume();
      });
    }
  });

  readableStream.on('end', () => {
    res.end();
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('sender is listening on port 3000');
});
```

The consumer service's code:

```
import express from 'express';
import axios from 'axios';
import util from 'util';
import { Transform } from 'stream';
const setTimeoutPromise = util.promisify(setTimeout);
const app = express();

app.get('/receive-stream', async (req, res) => {
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/stream', {
    responseType: 'stream',
  });

  const stream = response.data;

  const transform = new Transform({
    async transform(chunk, enc, callback) {
      await setTimeoutPromise(2);
      callback(null, chunk.toString().toUpperCase());
    },
  });

  stream.pipe(transform).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('consumer is running on port 4000');
});
```

(Call http://localhost:4000/receive-stream to test the whole workflow and mockData.js should be big enough to cause backpressure)

How I imagine the data transfer:
provider --> write buffer(provider side) --> read buffer(consumer side) --> consumer
The thing I don't understand is why does the draining of the write buffer(when it gets full) on the provider's side depend on the consumer's speed? As far as I understand, the provider should have no idea whether the consumer is able to accept more data because it is a one-way communication, however, when increasing the timeout on the consumer's side, the draining on the provider's write buffer takes longer. It would make sense to me if the streaming occurred in a single service(for example reading from a file and then writing to a file), but in this case the data is being streamed between services, so they should have no knowledge of each others' buffers. Could someone please explain what is it that I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand, the provider should have no idea whether the consumer is able to accept more data because it is a one-way communication

Well, from your perspective it is one-way, but it's a TCP connection underneath that HTTP connection, and TCP has flow control built into it.

When the consumer of the stream puts backpressure on, the networking buffers fill up quickly.  As packets received are acknowledged, a *window size* is also sent.  This window size indicates how much more data can be sent.  (In other words, the available buffer on the receiving client.)

Eventually, that window size becomes zero.  The host that's sending the data then knows it can't send anything more.  But, your application keeps writing anyway.  This fills a buffer on the writing side.

When you use the built-in streams, the streams track when they can write and when they can't.

So yes, basically, client puts on backpressure and this backpressure backs up all the way to the server eventually.